# Is there an automatic upvote for all questions with the tag "9th planet"? Or possibly a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I just posted [my first 9th planet question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13373/what-good-evidence-exists-for-the-9th-planet-as-spoken-of-by-caltech), and immediately (less than one second) got an upvote. I refreshed the page and it still said 1 view. I refreshed ten seconds later and still saw only 1 view.

Is there an automatic upvote for this? Or could it be a bug? If it's not automatic and the views are correct, then it would have to be a bug.

Comment: This is probably just an example of the knee-jerk voting that seems to be common on this and other SE sites. People don't actually read what you've written before making their minds up. I have seen some of my answers get upvotes literally within seconds of me posting them; they can't possibly have been read. Possibly it is more excusable when we're talking about a (short, simple) question. But your question was neither short nor simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Views are [heavily cached](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/438/1380), so it's not unusual to see a question stuck at 1 view for several minutes even after it's recieved a few votes. The vote your question received is from a fellow user and not in any way automatic. (But this is the most interesting conspiracy theory I've heard today. ;-)

Comment: Did you verify that by looking at some log and saw an actual username? I'm only asking because that upvote came extremely quickly (less than 1 second) and my question on the 9th planet had a lot to do with statistics, so yes I suppose I am suspicious of a conspiracy theory :)

Comment: @DrZ214: Yes, I know exactly which user voted. (And no, I'm not telling. ;-) I'm guessing someone read the question title and upvoted within 10 seconds. Presumably they finished reading the question and didn't change their mind during the 5 minute grace period.